# How to make changes in Inbound rules of multiple EC2 instances at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, port, aws-cli, aws-security-group

**This is the following scenario:**

*I have around 50 EC2 instances running in AWS. I need to open port-9100 in the inbound rules of all 50 instances. How can I make changes for all of them at once. Do we have any option in AWS to make changes like this?*

Comment: IaC is your friend

Comment: Is this a sample exam question, or is this an actual requirement of yours? If it is actual, please tell us whether all the instances have the _same_ Security Group.

Comment: This is an actual requirement and all the instances have different security groups.

Answer (score 3):

Use AWS CLI to get the security group id of each EC2 instance and update the security group.

Below command gets first security id of each EC2 instance (getting only first security group avoid adding the same rule on multiple security groups when more than one security group can be attached to an EC2 instance) and update the inbound rule.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[0].GroupId' --output=text | xargs -I {} aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id {} --protocol tcp --port 9100 --cidr 10.10.10.10/32
```

You can modify this command based on your requirement, apply filter if you want to apply security group modification only for a subset of EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

If all the instances already have a particular security group associated, you may simply be able to make one edit to that one security group and it will then affect all 50 instances.

If they don't share such a security group, you can automate to accomplish this.  For example, with the AWS CLI you could [create a new security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-security-group.html) that has the inbound rule you want, then loop through the 50 instances and [modify the security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html) to include the new one.  But the APIs don't support doing it in *one* API call--it would be a loop that makes an API call for each instance.  The console does not support changing this for  multiple instances at once either.

Similar APIs exist for using Python or another language instead of the CLI.